# How to call a function in more than one page in asp.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three different .aspx pages (abc1.aspx,abc2.aspx,abc3.aspx). Now I want to call one function `func()` in three of them. I want to define the definition of a function only 1 time and call it on 3 different pages.

Comment: Define a separate class, with function inside it, in each aspx code behind create object of that class and call the function

Answer (score 2):

Create base class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`. Define your function there. Then inherit from this base page instead of `System.Web.UI.Page` in those aspx pages. After this you can call the function from any of those pages like so: `base.MyFunct()`

**BasePage.cs**

```
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void MyFunct()
    {
    }
 }
```

**Page1.aspx.cs, Page2.aspx.cs, Page3.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Page1 : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.MyFunct();
    }
}

public partial class Page2 : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.MyFunct();
    }
}

public partial class Page3 : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.MyFunct();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add that the base class should be abstract.

Comment: This way you will avoid the need to instantiate a non-static helper class

Answer (score 2):

Add a .cs or .vb class file to your website appCode folder. 
Define your function in that code file
Example:

```
Class myFunctions
{
      public static int Sum(int a,int b)
      {
           return a+b;
      }
}
```

Now on your aspx code behind create an object of this class and use the function

```
int result = myFunctions.Sum(5,6);
```

Comment: The method should be static since you aren't using any state on the instance.

Comment: @Servy. sorry i'm unable to understand what you said. I have created the object of the class ? I'm not directly accessing the function. for static function I can access it with class name like myFunctions.Sum ? am i right

Comment: Your code will work, sure, but you're creating an instance of a class with no fields.  The function has no need for state; its output is entirely dependent on it's input.  Such functions *ought* to be static.  You will avoid creating a new object (which has a bunch of header information even without any state) when it doesn't do anything for you.

Comment: Unnecessary overhead of instantiating an object

Comment: @Servy ok I will use Static. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public class (optionally static) and add your method as a public static method to that class:

```
public class Utilities
{
  public static string DoStuff()
  {
    return "hello world";
  }
}
```

Comment: I try to use your method but didn't get success. I create a public class in `abc1.aspx`. But, I am unable to use it in `abc2.aspx`.

Comment: @Viktor The classes are likely in different namespaces.  Rather than adding the class to one of the aspx files, just add the class to the project as it's own file (to follow the standard convention).  Ensure that each of the aspx files adds a `using` statement for whatever namespace this class is in.  It's also possible you made this an inner class of your page, which you don't want.  If you did, that would also be solved by moving it to its own file.